# No qualified bean of type

Tags: java, spring

I can't figure out why Spring can't find my bean. I keep getting No Qualified bean of type TypeA when it enters the `@PostConstruct's applicationContext.getBean()` method. Here is my code:

```
public abstract class Base {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private Map<String, Base> baseTypes = new HashMap<String, Base>();

@PostConstruct
void initTypes() {
    baseTypes.put("typeA", applicationContext.getBean(TypeA.class));
}

public String sayHelloFrom(String type) {
    BaseType type = baseTypes.get(type);
    return type.sayHello();
}

protected abstract String sayHello();
}

@Component("typeA")
public class TypeA extends Base {


@Override
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello from A";
}
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: You should not work with a sub class in the super class

Comment: Have you put the below in your context file? `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.xx" />` Base package should contain your package that contains the classes that you have annotated with @Component

Comment: SashikaXP, yep - not exactly the same package, but the super package of mine is inside component-scan

Comment: Base package should contain your package that contains the classes that you have annotated with @Component

Comment: Just try `context.getBean("typeA")` without the .class at the end

Comment: What if you pull out @PostConstruct block in the TypeA class?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. SashikaXP was the closest answer. After I added the exact package where my component-annotated classed are, everything worked. This, kind of, conflicts with the component-scan feature, because I already had <context:component-scan base-package="base.package">, so I had to add <context:component-scan base-package="base.package.sub.package" but it solved my issue.